# Korolyuk's theorem and a set theoretical proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, stochastic-processes

I am looking at Stochastic Processes by Ross. In the middle of proving the Korolyuk's theorem, he said that (the successive symbols mean the intersection, and the bar means the complement):

$$A_k \overline{B_n} = \bigcup_{j=0}^{n-1} C_{nkj} \overline{B_n},$$ where

- $A_k=\{N(1) > k\}$,
- $B_{nj} = \{ N(\frac{j+1}{n}) - N(\frac{j}{n}) \geq 2\}$,
- $B_n = \bigcup_{j=0}^{n-1} B_{nj}$,
- $C_{nkj} = \{ N(\frac{j+1}{n}) - N(\frac{j}{n}) \geq 1, N(1) - N(\frac{j+1}{n}) = k \}$;

$\{N(t), t \leq 0 \}$ is a counting process.

But, I can't understand how we can say the equality of $A_k \overline{B_n} = \bigcup_{j=0}^{n-1} C_{nkj} \overline{B_n}$. It is hard for me to deal with something like these large sets.

Could you please explain this? Thanks!

Comment: What is $B_n$? You only seem to define $B_{nj}$?

Comment: @martini Sorry. I added the definition of $B_n$.

Comment: You mean $t\ge 0$, right? And do we have $N(0) = 0$ a. s.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event $\overline{B_n}$ means that between points $k/n$, there are no jumps greater than $1$; in other words, all jumps are equal to $1$. Now look at the first jump, occurring between $j/n$ and $(j+1)/n$, say. Then $N(j/n) = 0$, $N((j+1)/n) = 1$, so $N(1)>k$ is equivalent to $N(1) - N((j+1)/n)\ge k$, which, combined with $N(j/n) = 0$ and $N((j+1)/n) = 1$ is exactly $C_{nkj}$.